# Python websockets fast one way but 10x slower with response

Tags: python, performance, asynchronous, websocket, sanic

I have a sanic webserver running websockets, behind the scenes its using the "websockets" library.

Server

```py
from asyncio import sleep
from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic("websocket test")

@app.websocket("/")
async def test(_, ws):
    while True:
        data = await ws.recv()
        data = await ws.send('Hi')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

Client

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8000"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while iteration:
            await websocket.send("Hi")
            await websocket.recv()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

When I remove `ws.send('Hi')` from the server and `await websocket.recv()` from the client i can get 58000 messages a second, once I start listening for a response it goes all the way down to 6000 messages a second, I am just curious what is making this run 10x slower when the server responds.

Comment: I mean, how much time were you *expecting* it to take for that step? And what are you hoping we can tell you about it? It sounds like you have a tech support request for the developers of Sanic, not an actual question about programming.

Comment: I've posted it in the sanic tech support but as I was saying sanic is just using the websockets lib behind the scenes. I get the same performance with my own websockets server. I was hoping someone with websocket experience would have an answer as to why it's so much slower. I can get over 26000 requests per second using http on sanic. So. Fogured websockets would be a lot faster considering the smaller overhead.

Comment: "I get the same performance with my own websockets server" Then the issue may be intrinsic to the internet connection you are using, or to the machine you are running the server on.

Comment: Well it's localhost so quite literally nothing to do with the network outside of my machine. And my machine has no performance problems doing http requests or any other tcp connections. 3950x 4ghz. windows firewall disabled.

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution here would be to seperate your `send` and `recv` into seperate tasks so they can yield concurrently.

```py
async def producer(send):
    while True:
        await send("...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def consumer(recv):
    while True:
        message = await recv
        print(message)

async def test(request, ws):
    request.app.add_task(producer(ws.send)))
    request.app.add_task(consumer(ws.recv))
```

Obviously, this is a very simple example, and at the very least you should use some sort of a `Queue` for your producer.

But, when you break them into seperate tasks, then your `recv` is not blocked by `send`.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue when I have to send too many messages to the WebSocket server from the client, which is causing extreme slowness due to buffer. How can I solve this without the use of sanic?

Comment: @HarshPatel Ping me on the discord server and we can take your specific implementation issue there and have a back and forth if needed.

Comment: How can I reach you on discord? Got your Twitter, website, and GitHub but not seems to find you on discord.

Comment: @HarshPatel Sorry I missed this. Easiest place to find me is here: https://discord.gg/FARQzAEMAA